# Would regex be the better way to write code involving words and sentences?

Tags: python

I want to define a function that takes a sentence and returns the words that are at least a length of 4 and in lowercase. The problem is, I pretty new to Python and I'm not quite certain on how to make code dealing with words instead of integers. My current code is as follows:

```
def my_function(s):
    sentence = []
    for word in s.split():
        if len(word) >=4:
            return (word.lower())
```

If I `my_function("Bill's dog was born in 2010")` I expect `["bill","born"]` where as my code outputs `"bill's"`
From what I've seen on StackOverflow and in the Python tutorial, regular expression would help me but I do not fully understand what is going on in the module. Can you guys explain how regex could help, if it can at all?

Comment: "I expect `["bill", "born"]`" But earlier you said that the words must be at least length 4 and in lowercase. "Bill" isn't all lowercase, so why do you expect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are slightly inconsistent, so I'll go with your example as the reference.

```
In [27]: import re

In [28]: s = "Bill's dog was born in 2010"

In [29]: [w.lower() for w in re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z]{4,}\b', s)]
Out[29]: ['bill', 'born']
```

Let's take a look at the regular expression, `r'\b[A-Za-z]{4,}\b'`.

The `r'...'` is not part of the regular expression. It's a Python construct called a [*raw string*](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). It's like a normal string literal except backslash sequences like [`\b`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) don't have their usual meaning.

The two `\b` look for a word *boundary* (that is, the start or the end of a word).

The `[A-Za-z]{4,}` looks for a sequence of four or more letters. The `[A-Za-z]` is called a *character class* and consists of letters `A` through `Z` and `a` through `z`. The `{4,}` is a repetition operator that requires that the character class is matched at least four times.

Finally, the list comprehension, `[w.lower() for w in ...]`, converts the words to lowercase.

Comment: ...but it's not lowercase, which was a requirement in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Regex would be the simplest and easiest approach to achieve what you want.

Try this regex:

```
matches = re.findall(ur"\b[a-zA-Z]{4,}\b", "Put Your String Here") #matches [Your,String,Here]
```

Answer (score 0):

You return the first word that is 4 chars or longer, instead of all such words. Append to `sentence` and return that instead:

```
def my_function(s):
    sentence = []
    for word in s.split():
        if len(word) >=4:
           sentence.append(word.lower())
    return sentence
```

You can simplify that with a list comprehension:

```
def my_function(s):
    return [word.lower() for word in s.split() if len(word) >= 4]
```

Yes, a regular expression could do this too, but for your case that may be overkill.

Comment: Would prefer using re.split instead. string.split will fail for 'Hi, how are you?'.

Comment: @shantanoo: Perhaps, but my answer addresses what the OP did wrong in their own attempt without regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to accumulate the long words in 'sentence';) You're instead returning the first one

Answer (score 0):

Using re.split

```
>>> import re
>>> a='Hi, how are you today?'
>>> [x for x in re.split('[^a-z]', a.lower()) if len(x)>=4]
['today']
>>>
```